# 4-bit adder giving wrong output

Tags: computer-architecture

I tried to make a 4-bit adder, but it ain't working.
When I do this:

```
a 0000
b 1111
+ _____
s 0101
```

but s should be 1111!

[image: 4-bit adder]

And this is my 1bit-adder:

[image: 1-bit adder]

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to put a0123, and b0123 in just two 4-bit inputs instead of 8 separate inputs?

Comment: It looks to me that when you wired your 4-bit adder, you routed the sum output to the input of the next adder. In other words, you exchanged the sum and carry-out outputs in your top diagram.

Comment: @AmauryPouly Thanks that solved it! Any idea on how to replace the separate a0, a1, a2, and a3 with just one 4-bit input? Same for b?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on the software you are using (and might be unrelated to CS).

Comment: @AmauryPouly Logisim

Comment: You can set the bus width in the properties and use a splitter.

Comment: @AmauryPouly post as answer?